# Order by condition in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I've got two result columns. 
One is username and the other one is date-time which can check when each user viewed a post. If user hasn't seen the post, date-time value is NULL.

I'd like to order the data like this.
date-time is null or not null both are order by username alphabetically.
but null data and not null data should be separated.

```
SELECT u.username AS username,
       MAX(w1.date) AS lastdate
FROM w1
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN user_info u ON w1.userid = u.userid
WHERE u.usergroup = 'student'
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY lastdate,
         username;
```

When I run this query, the result I can get is 
username is ordered by alphabetically when date-time is NULL,
but when date-time is not null, it's ordered by date-time.

I hope you guys can understand, if it's not clear enough please leave a comment.

Comment: Not sure I understand your requirement I'm afraid. For your order by, it'll first put the rows which have the value `NULL` for `lastdate` (as `NULL` is treated as having the "lowest" value), and then it'll order the rows in date order, which the lowest first. If 2 rows have the same date, then it'll be sorted by the `username`.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is pretty much redundant in that query..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
order by case when lastdate is null then 0 
              else 1 end, username
```

Comment: Or shorter: `order by iif(lastDate is null, 0, 1), username`

Comment: @ZoharPeled Or even shorter  left(LastDate,0),username   In this case, left(...,0) will return either a null or empty string.

Comment: if SQL Server can use indexes on that @JohnCappelletti i believe SQL Server has some optimizer rewrite cases which could convert some cases of `LEFT()` usages

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using `left join` and phrasing the query as:

```
SELECT u.username AS username,
       MAX(w1.date) AS lastdate
FROM user_info u LEFT JOIN
     w1
     ON w1.userid = u.userid
WHERE u.usergroup = 'student'
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN w1.date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
         u.username;
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never appropriate with `GROUP BY`.

I also recommend qualifying all column references in a query that references multiple tables.